# Delphi FMX Listview bug in 10.4.2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, tlistview

Firemonkey in 10.4.2 (3 patches applied)

If drop a `TListview` with ItemAppearance=DynamicAppearance on a form, I can free it.  However, if I drop this TListview on another control, eg, TRectangle, and free it, it gave "Item cannot be found" error.  Visually, if you try to cut and paste the TListview (when it belongs to another control other than a Form, it also gave the same error.

This is surely a bug as Delphi 11 does not have this issue.  Does anyone know how to resolve it, as I need to stick to 10.4.2 for the time being.

```
object ListView1: TListView
  ItemAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
  ItemEditAppearanceClassName = 'TDynamicAppearance'
  HeaderAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
  FooterAppearanceClassName = 'TListHeaderObjects'
  Position.X = -16.000000000000000000
  Position.Y = 64.000000000000000000
  Size.Width = 321.000000000000000000
  Size.Height = 273.000000000000000000
  Size.PlatformDefault = False
  TabOrder = 3
  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
    item
      AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
      AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
    end>
  ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemEditObjects.ObjectsCollection = <
    item
      AppearanceObjectName = 'Text1'
      AppearanceClassName = 'TTextObjectAppearance'
    end>
end
```

Comment: I've got this exact error message: `...raised exception class EListError with message 'Item not found`

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's a bug in delphi 10.x.
Put on your Form's OnDestroy method the following and will avoid that error:

```
ListView1.Parent := nil;
```